# CSS Working for one Page but not Another

Tags: html, css

I have two pages utilizing the same CSS files. Essentially I want the header to be stuck to the top of the page, no margins. It works on my index page, but not the next page. More confusing still, it works in Codepen but not in my Visual Studio. I've checked the CSS link to both pages, and that works fine, the rest of the CSS works on both pages as it should. There is just this margin above one of the headers that isn't working. Inspect element shows all margins should be zero. 
[Incorrect (see black line at top?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkGmn.png)
[Correct (see no line?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzMHY.png)
HTML of Correct Page:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css">
    <title>Cauldron Luxury Bath</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sticky-menu">
        <header class="header">
            <h1 id="sticky-h1">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img class="headlogo" src="WebsiteLogo2.jpg" alt="Cauldron Logo" />
                </a>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul id="banner">
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="index-container">
```

HTML of Incorrect Page:

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css">
    <title>Cauldron Privacy Policy</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sticky-menu">
       <header class="header">
            <h1 id="sticky-h1">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img class="headlogo" src="WebsiteLogo2.jpg" alt="Cauldron Logo" />
                </a>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul id="banner">
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">News</a></li>  
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS Shared by Both:

```
body {
    background: black;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header {
    grid-area: a;
    margin-top:0;
}
.sticky-menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
#sticky-h1 {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background: white;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
.headlogo {
    width: 300px;
}
.nav {
    grid-area: b;
}
#banner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: darkgrey;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: dimgray;
}
.btn {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
#privacy-container {
    color: white;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
 }
#privacy-header{
    color:black;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to "inspect element" that margin. From where is it comming, if it is working in code pen. that means that something else is breaking your css. Some other html element or css rule

Comment: What is the uRL of next page? Something like `http://example.com/folder/nextpage.html`?

Comment: From the screenshot it looks to me like there's maybe an erroneous character in the HTML somewhere before `.sticky-menu`, though the code you've provided does not reproduce the error. Try setting the background to white to check.

Comment: Check if you have duplicated id's

Comment: Actually I added two <br/> to my HTML and that fixed it. So... not sure what happened or why. Is that cheating?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the #sticky-h1 has got a "padding-top: 20px".
You might need to remove that padding in order to get it stack to the top.
I also think that you just need  "margin: 0 auto;" once.

Please check the example below:
(I have used SO logo as I did not have yours)

```css
body, html {
    background: black;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header {
    grid-area: a;
    margin-top:0;
}
.sticky-menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#sticky-h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
.headlogo {
    width: 300px;
}
.nav {
    grid-area: b;
}
#banner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: darkgrey;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: dimgray;
}
.btn {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
#privacy-container {
    color: white;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
 }
#privacy-header{
    color:black;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body> 
    <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css">
    <title>Cauldron Privacy Policy</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sticky-menu">
       <header class="header">
            <h1 id="sticky-h1">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img class="headlogo" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" alt="Cauldron Logo" />
                </a>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul id="banner">
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">News</a></li>  
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="btn"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Following your comment, I have put the "padding-top: 20px" back and I have increased the margin of the "#banner" to 100px.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the padding and removing a few of the margin rules (I guess I got overzealous in my fight to find a solution, ha ha) did not help.

Comment: could be possible to upload a screenshot of your issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

So actually I added a break to the HTML under the sticky-menu and it fixed this issue. Not sure if that is the correct way to do it... but since it worked perhaps I won't worry too much...